# Solr returns error 500 for the term vector query

Tags: solr

in solr query web interface I want to get the terms vector values, for example the terms with the highest term frequency and so on.

For this I use a query `http://domain/tvrh?q=text:[* TO *]&wt=json&indent=true&tv.all=true&terms.fl=text`

I get following error for this query:

```
"termVectors": [
"uniqueKeyFieldName",
"_id",
"14708d4c-7145-46b7-98d0-727baff35ab9",
[
  "uniqueKey",
  "14708d4c-7145-46b7-98d0-727baff35ab9"
]
],
  "error": {
"trace": "java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.TermVectorComponent.process(TermVectorComponent.java:329)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:277)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2068)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:669)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:462)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:214)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
",
            "code": 500
```

Any ideas?

edit:

My schema.xml description field:

```
<field name="description" 
 type="text_general"
 indexed="true" 
 stored="true" 
 multiValued="true" 
 termVectors="true" 
 termPositions="true" 
 termOffsets="true"/>


<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stop-words-all-sorted.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stop-words-all-sorted.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

According to Karsten's suggestion, I use /terms to get term-frequency regardless the query. `http://localhost:8983/solr/core/terms?wt=json&indent=true&terms.fl=description`

I now get the terms frequency, however there is no single term shown but the whole text stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Nullpointer Exception caused by the result null of [IndexReader.html#getTermVectors](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVectors(int)) so most possible you have not indexed with  [TermVector](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Term+Vector+Component) (`termVectors="true"`).

You can add TermVectors in [field definition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields) of schema.xml. Example:

```
<field name="includes"
   type="text_general"
   indexed="true"
   stored="true"
   multiValued="true"
   termVectors="true"
   termPositions="true"
   termOffsets="true" />
```

Btw.:

If you want the document frequencies without restriction to a query you should use the [Terms Component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Terms+Component).

If you want the document frequencies restricted to a query you could use facetting (with "text" as facet).

Comment: Karsten, for the `text` field in the Schema Browser I have following flags selected: 


Flags:  Indexed  Tokenized  Stored  Multivalued

Comment: @Jakub, I added example how to insert the missing flag for termVectors.